# pd.describe() does not work

Tags: pandas, describe

```
from abupy import ABuSymbolPd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


tsla_df = ABuSymbolPd.make_kl_df('usTSLA', n_folds=8)


tsla_df [['close', 'volume']].plot (subplots = True, style = ['r', 'g'],
                                grid = True)


print tsla_df [ ['close', 'volume']]

plt.show()
tsla_df.info()
tsla_df.describe(include = "all")
```

---

In above python code, I hope last code list the statistical of tsla_df, but it does not and also never give any error information. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: what does `type(tsla_df)` return? if it's not a `pandas` `DataFrame` then this won't work

Comment: it seems you forget `print` like `print tsla_df.describe(include = "all")` ?

Comment: >>> type (tsla_df)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  looks normal.

Comment: jezrael, you are right. Thanks!